# ARM EABI toolchain: how to rebuild newlib-nano with exceptions enabled on windows 10?

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I'm using MCUXpresso with a C++ project on a Cortex M0+.

Today I ran into an issue: my very simple `try catch` block was not working, it was always calling the terminate handler.

I found out the issue was due to newlib-nano having exceptions handling disabled by default. See https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/230716.

In this project, I don't want to use newlib, it would simply not fit into the small flash of the chip I am using.

I am re using a lot of code using exceptions, I would rather spend some time adding the support to newlib nano than modify all the existing code base...

So for someone who has never built an ARM lib, what would be the steps to follow to build libstdc++ (nano version, toolchain version 8.3.1) with exceptions enabled on Windows?

Comment: Unfortunately, using exceptions with GCC-ARM-Embedded and newlib(-nano) requires at least 100KiB of flash and also a lot of SRAM, so you probably have to live without them.

Comment: You should definitively not attempt to do this on native Windows 10. You should  rather use WSL or WSL2, or install VirtualBox and a Ubuntu LTS Linux.